# Words with a negative definition

Tags: definition

In my secret Asian language, it’s acceptable saying for example “very not comfortable” for “very uncomfortable” which is unacceptable in English.

What I wonder about is why for example “very uncomfortable” doesn’t mean “not very comfortable,” but means “very uneasy”?

Comment: **Uncomfortable** is a word that can apply equally to a person's state of body or of mind.

Comment: Why "secret"?  Is there some kind of shame in speaking this Asian language now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Very" is an intensifier. The words "uncomfortable" and "uneasy" can be seen as having a positive meaning, though they are constructed as negatives. The intensification of "very" is applied to that meaning.

In the phrase "not very comfortable", the intensification of "very" applies to "comfortable", and the negation of "not" applies to the resulting meaning.

The word order is important in English.

Answer (score 1):

"Uncomfortable" can have the meaning "uneasy" or "not comfortable", so "not very comfortable" could mean either one. It should be clear from the context what the intended meaning is.

Also, "not very comfortable" does not mean "very uncomfortable" or "very uneasy". It means "somewhat uncomfortable, but not very uncomfortable".

Comment: That's not how your question reads. You asked why "very uncomfortable" doesn't mean "not very comfortable". You mention "very not" in the first sentence, but don't ask any question about it.